# Can I remove Bing maps from Outlook 365 ProPlus?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, bing

I was just upgraded to Office 365 ProPlus and now have "Bing Maps" showing up in my emails.  Is there a way to remove/disable this from Outlook?

Comment: When viewing an email that contains an address it shows a bar that says "Bing Maps" in a bar after the header info (from, to, date) and before the message body.  On the right hand side of the bar, it has a "Get more apps" link.  I can't find how to uninstall the Bing Maps app/add-in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Outlook, click on the file menu and scroll down to the bottom of the **Info section** and select "**Manage Apps**". This will take you to a webpage managing what add-ins are setup by default (probably by your administrator). In here, you can simply disable the Bing Maps add-on and it should no longer show that bar.

It's important to note that this is a different add-in section that previously mentioned here. This Manage Apps button is in the info page, **not** under options.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The app was installed by my company and I am able to uninstall it, but I am able to disable.  Thanks!

Comment: In the version of Office used here the option is called "Manage Add-ins" rather than "Manage Apps" but this indeed allows you to enable/disable plugins.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the browser version of outlook and go to options. Here is a direct link https://outlook.office365.com/ecp
2. Click on add-ins on the left
3. Click on Bing Maps
4. On the right side of the screen you will see a link to disable.

This is the only place I've found to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Follow all the steps above and uncheck "Outlook Social Connector 2013"

It removed it.  At least I cant see it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an Add-In. Here's how to disable add-ins in Outlook 2013:

> To access the Outlook add-ins management window, open Outlook and go
>   to File -> Options (for Outlook 2013) and go the Add-ins section.
>
> You can’t remove Outlook add-ins directly here, but you can remove
>   them by clicking on the “Go” button located after the “Manage COM
>   Add-ins” text. This will popup a new window which will show all
>   add-ins (enabled and disabled).
>
> Here you can locate the desired add-in and remove it from Outlook. You
>   can remove the Outlook add-in either by un-checking its check-box or
>   by selecting it and clicking on the Remove button.
>
> Attention: if you remove an Outlook add-in using the Remove button,
>   the add-in will be removed completely from the list of available
>   Outlook add-ins. If you later decide to enable it back, it may be
>   tricky to find its library file.
>
> It is important to know that, if you remove Outlook add-ins using this
>   method, the add-ins are not actually deleted from your computer: they
>   are only removed from the list of available Outlook add-ins. They will
>   not load in Outlook anymore, but their add-in files are not erased
>   from your computer.

Source: http://www.outlook-apps.com/remove-outlook-add-ins/

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an add-in as well.  Unfortunately, if I look at my list of "COM Add-Ins", there's nothing listed that refers to Bing and/or maps.

Comment: Try the first option from the source link, it shows how to remove add-ins from the control panel.

Comment: My list of programs doesn't show anything for Outlook or Bing.  However, I was wrong, I don't just have Office 2013, I have Office 365 ProPlus (I've updated question).  Maybe it's a part of that and can't be uninstalled separately.

Comment: It's probably a browser add-in. Are you accessing outlook through a browser (firefox, IE, chrome)?

Comment: No, I am opening Outlook deskdtop app.